# F# converting hmac python into f#

Tags: hash, f#, sha

How would I convert this Python code into F# "

```py
message = nonce + client_id + api_key
signature = hmac.new(API_SECRET, msg=message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()
```

My code so far to achieve this:

```
let message =string(nonce)+ client_id + api_key
let signature = HMACSHA256.Create(API_secret+message)
```

Simple issue is I cannot find what represents the `hexdigest()` function in F#.

Also, do I combine the `API_Secret` with the message as I have done or must they be separated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need somethink like this:

```
let hexdigest (bytes : byte[]) =
   let sb = System.Text.StringBuilder()
   bytes |> Array.iter (fun b -> b.ToString("X2") |> sb.Append |> ignore)
   string sb

let signature =
   use hmac = new HMACSHA256.Create(API_secret)
   hmac.ComputeHash(message)
   |> hexdigest
```

The part with the StringBuilder is what `hexdigest` does in python (if I get `hexdigest` right)

Comment: Does message have to be a byte array?

Comment: for this method yes - you have to convert it yourself - for text the easiest way are the methods/classes in System.Text.Encoding - for example this one encodes a string using UTF8: `let utf8EncodedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes myString`

Comment: according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c9tf8wc(v=vs.110).aspx HMAC creation should be:

`use hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(secret)`

Comment: true - you'll get a warning - it's more a convention though but I will fix it - thanks